# Setting audio element volume with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set the volume of my audio element using JavaScript but I can't get it to actually change. I'll console log audio.volume and it shows that it's set to whatever I set it to in the JS but doesn't actually affect the volume.
(Trying to set it to 0 just to see if it mutes)

Here is my Code

HTML

```
<audio id="audio" v-if="image.play == true" loop autoplay>
   <source v-bind:src="image.audio" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

JS

```
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
audio.volume = 0;
```

Comment: I know you've posted this question quite three years ago but I had the same problem, if you provide your code I might be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.volume = 0.2;
</script>
```

You can change the volume from 0.0 (silenced) to 1.0 (loud) with HTML5.

Comment: How is this different than the OP's code? Sure, you're using `.getElementById` in place of `querySelector` but both of those will select the same DOM element if there's only one `<audio>` on the page.

Comment: Yeah, that code is the same as mine. Doesn't change the volume at all. I am using VueJS to generate multiple audio elements. I'm not sure if that could be causing the issue.